# Newbie Questions (Regarding From Datetime Import Datetime)

Tags: python

I came across this code to count how much days I have til my birthday.

I know the difference between 'from import' and 'import' however I am confused because based on the code below, the second function named 'days_remaining' I was able to write in the variable days = (current_year - now).days. But if I recall correctly, days is a method/attribute under timedelta and I shouldn't be able to use that if I wrote from datetime import datetime because I am specifically importing only datetime method in the module.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

def get_user_birthday():
  date_str = input("Enter your birth date in DD/MM/YYYY: ")
  try:
    birthday = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d/%m/%Y")
  except TypeError:
    birthday = datetime.datetime(*(time.strptime(date_str, "%d/%m/%Y")[0:6]))
  return birthday

def days_remaining(birth_date):
  now = datetime.now()
  current_year = datetime(now.year, birth_date.month, birth_date.day)
  days = (current_year - now).days
  if days < 0:
    next_year = datetime(now.year+1, birth_date.month, birth_date.day)
    days = (next_year - now).days
  return days

birthday = get_user_birthday()
next_birthday = days_remaining(birthday)
print("Your birthday is coming in: ", next_birthday, " days")
```

Comment: The subtraction of two `datetimes` creates as `timedelta`, no need to import it explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to explicitly call something from `timedelta` you need to `import` it; but the date arithmetic functions in `datetime.datetime` will sometimes return a `datetime.timedelta` object whose methods you can then access directly, often without reflecting on, or even knowing, its type or methods.

Internally, subtraction using the arithmetic minus `-` operation simply calls the `__sub__` method of the first operand; this is how you are able to use (what looks like) simple subtraction on objects which are not numbers (and, as a matter of fact, also objects which *are* numbers :-)

To reiterate, `datetime.datetime` has to import `datetime.timedelta`, but it can then return an object created by this module to you, and you don't have to know or care that it did. As long as the returned object supports the methods you are calling on it, you will be fine.

More generally, many libraries which you `import` will give you back objects of types you didn't have to `import`, from that module, or another one entirely. You only need to explicitly `import` something if you explicitly want to refer to a symbol from that module (catch a named error, instantiate or inherit from a specific class, etc). The rest of the time (and it probably happens more often than you would imagine at first) you don't need to pay much attention to this, because it's just a relatively insignificant implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you - why is this the case? (I'm guessing the relevant things, subtract and days, are lower level in date (or some lower level library)? so as to allow timedelta even when timedelta is not explicity called by the program)

Comment: Looking at the code for lib/datetime I see the following, which I think would support the above hypothesis: ```import time as _time
import math as _math
import sys
from operator import index as _index``` This library can be found here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/datetime.py as referenced from here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime

Comment: Yeah, the current CPython implementation in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/datetime.py is encapsulating a bunch of C code actually. This exposition attempts a beginner-friendly simplification of the real deal.

Comment: @tripleee ah so the trigger that allowed it to use the timedelta method/attributes is the arithmetic "-" is it? But why is that so?

Comment: No, it's much simpler than that. Subtraction simply looks for `__sub__`; if the object doesn't have that method, you get an error. Multiplication looks for `__mul__`, `len` looks for `__len__`, etc etc. Most of the time you don't need to know or care about this because inheritance takes care of making sure that the methods you need are already there. The one place you need to do it yourself is if you want to override a method with one of your own.

Comment: @tripleee I see, is so this __sub__ & __mul__ is from the math library? And is it just as simple as subtracting it as an integer? How is it named as days though? PS. Sorry if I am asking dumb questions, just want to really understand through x.x

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. These are just examples of how Python's "primitive" operators are implemented as wrappers for methods you can override for each type. The real beef in the answer is that you don't have to import things to use them, only to explicitly refer to their names.

Comment: I mean like when I write days = (current_year - now).days, it was able to use days from timedelta because it is over-rided as just a simple subtraction is it? it's not actually from timedelta.

Comment: The subtraction uses code from `timedelta` but it does not need to load that module to find that code. The object in `current_year` has a `__sub__` method (which was ultimately defined in `timedelta` when this object was created) so the subtraction operator simply calls that. In very precise terms, check if this object has a `__sub__` attribute and try to call that (otherwise throw an error along the lines of "unsupported operand type"); then you check whether the result has a `.days` attribute, and return that (otherwise fail with "has no attribute 'days'")

Comment: @tripleee, Thank you so much for the explanation. May I ask is the __sub__ function in the timedelta class written in line 620 from the github link?
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/datetime.py

Comment: That's the one, yes. `class timedelta` starts on line 420 and continues through line 755 in this version.

Comment: Alright, I understand now. I am so glad StackOverflow exists with people like you helping out others in the forum. Thanks again!  @tripleee